# Javascript argument into function to find spot in array

Tags: javascript

This javascript function works well for reading values from an object when it is hardcoded.

```
function showNote(){
document.write(notes.B[1]);
}
```

But I can't get it to work with a variable. I would like to do something like this, but I get an undefined variable message.

```
<script>
showNote(B)
</script>

function showNote(y){
console.log(y);
document.write(notes.y[1]);
}
```

Comment: it should be `showNote('B')` and `notes[y][1]`. See the duplicate question for more details.

Comment: Another reason it would be failing is that you can't access variable property names using dot notation. You probably want `document.write(notes[y][1])`.